# access nested value in json

Tags: javascript, json

I want to access the coordinates:

```
{
    "name":"String",
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {"type":"Feature", "geometry": {"type":"Point", "coordinates":[10,11]}},
        {...},
        {...}]
}
```

I already tried:

```
var jsonfile = $.getJSON("myjsonfile.json");
for(var i = 0, l = jsonfile.features; i < l; i++) {
  var obj = json.features[i];
  console.log(obj.coordinates[1]);
}
```

But this doesn't work. I don't know why...

Comment: `obj.features[0].geometry.coordinates` by the looks of it.

Comment: Is it `array` of `objects`?

Comment: i get undefined in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
```

The object contains an array called `features` the first element of which is another object called `geometry`, one property of which is an array called `coordinates`.

So, the iteration would be something like:

```
var jsonfile = $.getJSON("myjsonfile.json", function (data) {
    for (var i = 0, l = data.features.length; i < l; i++) {
        var coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
        var lat = coords[0];
        var lng = coords[1];
        // plot lat, lng
    }
});
```

Comment: I think, OP want all the `coordinates` from the object array

Comment: `getJSON` is asynchronous. Even if he'd fix the loop, this still wouldn't work.

Comment: i get undefined in Chrome

Comment: Yeah, I missed that the first time round. @plasmid0h, the answer shows you how to use `getJSON` properly for an asynchronous request.

Comment: i still get undefined in the console ? :/

Comment: @plasmid0h, doh, I missed the length attribute off the loop. See if it works now. [Here's a demo that mimics `getJSON`](http://jsfiddle.net/o7o5u2w7/2/). You should check that you're actually receiving data from `getJSON`.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand.

Comment: In your callback, check that you're actually getting data returned before you loop over it. [See the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7o5u2w7/3/). If you're not, that's a separate problem.